# ActionBarSherlock: getSupportMenuInflator() is undefined

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using **ActionBarSherlock** and trying to inflate my XML menu by using `getSupportMenuInflator()`, but it is giving an error:

```
the method getSupportMenuInflator() is undefined for the type ...
```

I'm unable to figure out why it's showing the error. Here is the code:

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    ...
}
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Have you included the ABS library with the project.?

Comment: yes, that's the first thing I did.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use:

```
getSherlockActivity().getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
```

Since `getSupportMenuInflater()` is a method in SherlockActivity not SherlockFragment.

Comment: Ok. Got it. But now it's giving an error that : the method inflate(int,Menu) in the type MenuInflater is not applicable for the arguments (int,Menu)??

Comment: You need to import the ABS Menu and MenuItem classes: `import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;`
`import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;` not the Android versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **SherlockActionBar** you should `implement SherlockActivity` **instead of** `Activity and getSupportMenuInflater()` will be avaliable