# ABS - Fragments - Menu inflation issue

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-menu

So im getting the following problem `getSupportMenuInflater() is undefined`.

This project is using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) libraries.

I'm sure this issue is not related to my imports for ABS, however it only seems to be happening in my actual Fragment class which  `extends SherlockFragment` However i have no problem with menu items in my Main class which `extends SherlockFragmentActivity`

Now i've tried simply changing my fragment class to extend `SherlockFragmentActivity`. However in doing so i am then force to remove all `@Override`'s and then i end with the following error

`The method onActivityCreated(Bundle) is undefined for the type SherlockFragmentActivity`.

Code

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater Inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    Inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;    
    }
```

**Resolved** Updated code to the following.

```
 public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSherlockActivity().getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return;
```

Comment: you can get clue from this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222466/actionbarsherlock-getsupportmenuinflator-is-undefined

Comment: @Rstar Thanks, post as answer so i accept.

Comment: just posted in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
getSherlockActivity().getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
```

Since `getSupportMenuInflater()` is a method in SherlockActivity not SherlockFragment.

[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14222596/1218762)